# Determine different pairs

Tags: data, filtering

Let's create a sample data

```
data = {{0.21,0,0},{-3.2,2,1},{0.03,4,3},{3.1,0,0},{5.23,3,2},{8.02,1,1},{-2.4,2,1},{3.3,0,0},{1.02,1,1},{0.07,5,6}};
```

Each element of the list contains one real number and two integers. We are only interested in integers. We want to find how many different pairs of integers exist in the data list. In particular, we need to create a second list `data2`, containing all the different types in the form $nm$. For the above example, the list should be

```
data2 = {00, 21, 43, 32, 11, 56};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@
 FromDigits /@ DeleteDuplicates[
   Cases[#, _Integer] & /@ data]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pairs = DeleteDuplicates @ (Rest /@ data)
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 1}, {5, 6}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]

f1 = Map[StringRiffle[#, ""] &] @ DeleteDuplicates @ #[[All, -2 ;;]] &;

f1 @ data
```

> ```
>  {"00", "21", "43", "32", "11", "56"}
> ```

```
f2 = Map[FromDigits] @ DeleteDuplicates @ #[[All, -2 ;;]] &;

f2 @ data
```

> ```
>  {0, 21, 43, 32, 11, 56}
> ```

```
f3 = Map[Row] @ DeleteDuplicates @ #[[All, -2 ;;]] &;
f3 @ data
```

> [image]

Comment: Well, how you remove the first column with the unwanted real numbers?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, `Rest/@data` removes the first column.

Comment: And if we want to remove the first four columns and leave the last two ones?

Comment: `data[[All, -2;;]]` is more general.

Comment: A minor comment: is there a quick way to see the percentage of each pair?

Comment: maybe  `#/Total[#] &@Counts[data[[All, -2 ;;]]]` ?